# Change ebay.co.uk listings default currency

Tags: ebay

Is it possible to change the default currency on ebay.co.uk listings from British Pound Sterling to Euro?

Comment: Check [this](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-set-the-default-currency-on-ebay/) solution.

Comment: @Alex unfortunately there's no "Advanced Options" in "View > Customize" as said in the article. This was written 3 years ago so I guess this option has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ebay.ie](http://ebay.ie), it lists the same products as [ebay.co.uk](http://ebay.co.uk) but the default currency is in €.

Comment: Thanks Tuga. Indeed Ireland's ebay.ie, like Germany's ebay.de, can list the items in €, but they don't have the same products. For example a search of "raspberry pi" yields 2475 results in `.ie` and 3375 in `.co.uk`.

Comment: Just change the search filter to include ALL listings

Answer (score 1):

To pay your fees in a different billing currency, go to the **[Switch Billing Currency](https://arbd.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SBCChooseCurrency)** page and select the appropriate currency from the drop-down menu.

When you change your billing currency, eBay opens a new currency account under your current user ID.

**NOTE: THIS IS ONLY SOLUTION FOR SELLER ACCOUNT**